# Plotting the Likelihood Function, Prior Distribution, and Posterior Distribution in R

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

So for my problem, there are n=10,000 people involved in a clinical trial. Each has probability θp of getting a virus after receiving a vaccine. We are given that θp ∈ (0,1) .

I've determined my likelihood function to be Y∼Binomial(n,θp) , and my prior to be

Beta(α,β) , thus giving me a posterior distribution equal to Beta(A,B) where A=Y+α , and B=n−Y+β.

I want to plot all these on a single graph. Here is what I have tried:

```
# Creating likelihood function
n <- 10000
success <- 0:n
likelihood <- dbinom(success, size = n, prob = .5) # p = 0.5 chosen WLOG

# Creating the prior distribution
p <- seq(0,1, length = n)
alpha <- 1 # shape parameters alpha and beta  chosen arbitrarily to be equal to 1 
beta <- 1
prior <- dbeta(success, shape1 = alpha, shape2 = beta)

# Creating the posterior distribution
Y <- 7000 # chosen WLOG
posterior <- dbeta(success, shape1 = (Y + alpha), shape2 = (n - Y + beta))

# Making the plots
plot(success, data , type = "l",  col = "blue")
lines(success, prior, type = "l",  col = "red")
lines(success, posterior, type = "l",  col = "green")
```

However, when I plot these functions, I'm getting this as an error:

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Any help fixing this issue and getting my plots to work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! I'm still new to R and plotting is something I'm still getting acquainted with. I thought I made everything okay by making sure they're still being plotted over my domain I've labeled "success" but I guess not? I'm just not sure where the error is coming from. Thanks again!

Comment: where should I try that? In the plot() and lines() commands?

Comment: `success` is length `n + 1` not `n`, i thought that was the problem, but it is actually that you have not defined `data` in `plot(success, data)`, so r finds the function, `data()`, which `length(data)` is 1. assuming you meant `plot(success, likelihood)`